# Jquery dynamic ul foreach array

Tags: jquery, arrays, foreach, html-lists, each

Simple question. I have a dynamic list being generated from a REST api. here is my code.

```
   $.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url:'../endpoint/?tid='+$id,
   success: function(tracking){

       tracking = tracking.data[0];

       $.each(tracking, function(i,tracking){
           $parcel.append(
           '<li>Carrier: '+ tracking.carrier + '</li>'+
           '<li> Tracking Number:' + tracking.tracking_num +'</li>'
              );

       })
```

here is what is returned

```
<ul id="Parcel">
 <li> Carrier: FedEX</li>
 <li>Tracking Number: 10</li>
 <li> Carrier: DHL/li>
 <li>Tracking Number: 20</li>
</ul>
```

I need that this instead for each array returned in the $.each loop.

```
<ul id="Parcel">
 <li> Carrier: FedEX</li>
 <li>Tracking Number: 10</li>
</ul>
<ul>
 <li> Carrier: DHL/li>
 <li>Tracking Number: 20</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just add it to your `append`?

You could first have the main `div` or `ul` that you want (e.g. `<div id="Parcel">`) and then append the `ul`s to that `div` accordingly.

```
   $.each(tracking, function(i,tracking){
       $parcel.append(
       '<ul>'+
       '<li>Carrier: '+ tracking.carrier + '</li>'+
       '<li> Tracking Number:' + tracking.tracking_num +'</li>'+
       '</ul>'
          );

   })
```

Comment: I swear I did this... it didn't work but now it does. Thanks Sina

Comment: you had perhaps missed a little `+` sign or something. No worries mate. Happy coding :)